# inserting huge ammount of rows into mysql useing C# from csv file

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, csv

i need to insert data from csv files the dates strings ints code every file have about 28column and 6000 rows i need to insert the data of multiple file when clicking on a buttom i tryed to insert them row by row using the sql insert statment but it take around 2 mins to finish and sometimes crash i need some help to make the proccess faster and smooth i usually check if a row is inserted thus no rows with same data are inserted into the database any help would be appreciated

Comment: `load data infile`:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html.

Comment: if it is possible to make insert time less than  mins i would be glad

Comment: when i try to use the load data infile it give me error when i excute the command incorrect syntax near 'LOCAL' if i remove local it give me near infile tho i checked the line and seems to me there is nothing wronge

Answer (score 0):

If there are a lot of duplicates in the files, you could load all rows into a list and use the [Distinct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method in System.Linq before inserting into the database. The type contained in the list would implement the [IComparable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface.

Comment: its max of an 20 row duplicate but the main issue is the time the program take to insert the rows into the database i hope there is a way that is faster than row by row insert that what i was searching for

Comment: If it is more of MySQL problem you might want to try inserting multiple rows at once e.g.

INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);

MySQL Insert: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html